# Unable to resolve function name 'ErrorEmail'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I've developed a consumption-based Azure Function, triggered by an Azure Service Bus topic (don't think this is related to service bus or topics). I noticed the following error in my log:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve function name 'ErrorEmail'.
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.FunctionInstanceLogger.d__6.MoveNext() in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\Diagnostics\FunctionInstanceLogger.cs:line 80
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.CompositeFunctionEventCollector.d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__13.MoveNext()
```

The function is normally running thousands of times each day and this is the only instance of this error.

This is probably an internal problem on Azure since none of my code has been triggered at this point. But do anyone know if there is something I can do about this?

Comment: Can you share your function name privately by following the below link so that I can look at the logs. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately

Comment: Here is the id: 13bdc67c-6a83-42c2-a316-32b4be8952ca. The error happened on 2019-06-01T13:33:32Z

Comment: Thomas I believe function app has been deleted at 2019-06-04 08:12:39.793.

Comment: Oh, yeah that's correct. Totally forgot about this and moved the function to v2.

Comment: Maybe I should just monitor if this happens on v2 and create a new question if it does? I can see that it is hard to debug without the storage.

Comment: Sure. Will let me know if you observe this again in V2.